# How does MIPS I handle branching on the previous ALU instruction without stalling?

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

```
        addiu   $6,$6,5
        bltz    $6,$L5
        nop
        ...
$L5:
```

How is this safe without stalling, which classic MIPS couldn't even do, except on cache miss?
(MIPS originally stood for Microprocessor Without Interlocked Pipeline Stages, and had a load delay slot instead of interlocking.)

Original MIPS I is a classic 5-stage RISC `IF ID EX MEM WB` design that hides all of its branch latency with [a single branch-delay slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285354/why-do-longer-pipelines-make-a-single-delay-slot-insufficient) by checking branch conditions early, in the ID stage (correction: this was the mistake, go read this answer; don't be misled by the rest of the details in the question based on this false premise).  Which is why it's limited to equal/not-equal, or sign-bit checks like lt or ge zero, not lt between two registers that would need carry-propagation through an adder.

**Doesn't this mean that branches need their input ready a cycle earlier than ALU instructions?**  The `bltz` enters the ID stage in the same cycle that `addiu` enters EX.

MIPS I (aka R2000) uses [bypass forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Solution_A._Bypassing) from EX-output to EX-input so normal integer ALU instructions (like a chain of `addu`/`xor`) have single-cycle latency and can run in consecutive cycles.

---

MIPS stands for "Microprocessor without [Interlocked Pipeline Stages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Solution_B._Pipeline_interlock)", so it doesn't detect RAW hazards; code has to avoid them.  (Hence load-delay slots on first-gen MIPS, with MIPS II adding interlocks to stall in that case, invalidating the acronym :P).

But I never see any discussion of calculating the branch condition multiple instructions ahead to avoid a stall.  (The addiu/bltz example was emitted by MIPS gcc5.4 `-O3 -march=mips1` [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27void+storecond(int+*a,+int+*b,+int+x)+%7B%0A++++x+%2B%3D+5%3B%0A++++if+(x%3C0)%0A++++++++*a+%3D+x%3B%0A++++else%0A++++++++*b+%3D+x%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+load_delay(int+**p)+%7B%0A++++return+1+%2B+**p%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+loadbranch_delay(int+*p)+%7B%0A++++if+(*p)%0A+++++++return+5%3B%0A++++else%0A+++++++return+2%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.68013929135108,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips5,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-xc+-Wall+-march%3Dmips1%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27MIPS+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:42.71263230348839,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-xc+-Wall+-target+mips+-fomit-frame-pointer%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:53.31986070864893,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), which *does* respect load-delay slots, filling with `nop` if needed.)

---

Does it use some kind of trick like EX reading inputs on the falling edge of the clock, and ID not needing forwarded register values until the rising edge?  (With EX producing its results early enough for that to work)

I guess that would make sense if the clock speed is capped low enough for cache access to be single-cycle.

[Stalling or bubble in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092182/stalling-or-bubble-in-mips) claims that `lw` + a `beq` on the load result needs *2* stall cycles because it can't forward.  That's not accurate for actual MIPS I (unless gcc is buggy).  It does mention half clock cycles, though, allowing a value to be written and then read from the register file in the same whole cycle.

Comment: I seem to recall seeing a diagram of actual MIPS propagation-delay timings for parts of various stages sometime in the last few months / half a year.  I think it did have the EX result ready early and have ID not need it until the 2nd phase of the clock.  But I don't remember where I saw that, or if it was actually for MIPS instead of some other ISA.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the CPU just stalls (inserts a bubble) and that the "without Interlocked Pipeline Stages" was never true for any commercially released MIPS processor. It's hard to be sure because pretty all I can find on the MIPS pipeline are course slides that might not be talking about a real CPU. Note that stall would also be required with `lw $6, ($6)` `nop` `bltz $6, $L5` because the one instruction load delay slot is not enough.

Comment: Part of the confusion here maybe the result of the fact that the MIPS I architecture wasn't the first MIPS architecture, before it came the Stanford MIPS architecture. This original architecture was the one that didn't have interlocks. It also didn't have byte addressing. https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/infk/inst-cs/lst-dam/documents/Publications/mips_retrospective.pdf

Comment: @RossRidge: Unfortunately we can't assume that gcc makes optimal code, but its instruction scheduling in an unrolled loop (https://godbolt.org/z/WLdSCz) doesn't avoid computing branch inputs right before testing them (which it could and should if that leads to a stall, for performance not correctness reasons).  Although from playing around with variations on the loop, it does often avoid that when there's a bit more work in the loop.  So we just can't tell if it's a missed opt or if it's actually fine on MIPS I.  (And GCC's MIPS tuning cares some about superscalar MIPS.)

Comment: Yah, I did a quick check of the GCC sources to see if it did anything to avoid the stall and couldn't find anything. I also did a quick check of the GNU assembler. because it also does its own reordering, but didn't find anything.

Comment: @RossRidge: I'm confident that there's no actual correctness problem.  That part of the question I posted was mostly a way to introduce the topic.  So I certainly wouldn't expect to find anything about it in any assembler, unlike the optional reordering of independent instructions, or NOP insertion, to fill branch-delay slots.

Comment: As I see it, when `bltz` enters `ID` along with `addiu` entering `EX`, they have a whole clock to stabilise their output and write the result in the interstage latches/register. So `EX` simply forward the registers while `ID` initially uses the old value but the new one arrives in time for its value to propagates through the `ID` conditions checking gates. Basically, like you said with the falling/rising edge though this may actually be a combinatoric (not clock based) and not a sequential net (which would make it a "pipelined" ID stage).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: turns out MIPS doesn't need to start IF until the 2nd half of a clock; that's where the half-clock thing I was remembering came in.  Posted an answer to this mystery that finally makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL:DR:** Classic MIPS I checks branch conditions in the first half cycle of EX, so forwarding *to* them is not special.

IF only needs the address in the 2nd half of a cycle so EX can forward to it.

These factors combine to give only 1 cycle of branch latency (hidden by 1 delay slot), with no problem for branches that depend the previous ALU instruction.

---

**It was definitely safe to run `sltu` / `beq` on MIPS I (R2000)**.  That's listed as the expansion for the `bgeu` pseudo-instruction, for example, in real MIPS manuals and books with no caveat about it being unsafe on MIPS R2000 or any other MIPS.

GCC uses sequences like that in practice even with `march=mips1` which respects load-delay slots and other features of real MIPS R2000.

---

**MIPS's IF doesn't need an address until the 2nd half of a clock cycle, allowing EX to produce it quickly enough.**

From [See MIPS Run](https://doc.lagout.org/electronics/doc/mips/See%20mips%20run.pdf#page=35) by Dominic Sweetman, (covering MIPS I through MIPS IV), Chapter *1.5.1 Constraints on Instructions*

> We’ll see later that efficient conditional branching means that the decision about whether to branch or not has to be squeezed into only half
>   a pipeline stage; the architecture helps out by keeping the branch decision tests very simple. So conditional branches (in MIPS) test a single
>   register for sign/zero or a pair of registers for equality.

Their *Figure 1.3: The pipeline and branch delays* shows the branch condition being calculated in the first half of EX, and used in the 2nd half of IF, for a total branch latency of only 1 cycle / pipeline stage (ID) / instruction.  **IF doesn't actually start until the 2nd half of a clock cycle.**  (And continues into ID.  The actual decode/register-fetch of ID only takes the last fraction of a clock cycle.)

**That has the same end result as what I suggested in the question (check branch condition by the end of ID), except it only requires EX -> EX forwarding to branch on the result of the previous ALU instruction.**

Perhaps I was misremembering or misinterpreting something I'd read previously about the half-cycle branch-decision.  This half-cycle thing might well be exactly what I remembered seeing.

Further quoting *See MIPS Run* 1.5.5 Programmer-Visible Pipeline Effects

> • Delayed branches: [first paragraph explains the branch-delay slot]
>
> If nothing special was done by the hardware, the decision to branch or
>   not, together with the branch target address, would emerge at the end
>   of the ALU pipestage — in time to fetch the branch target instruction
>   instead of the next instruction but two. But branches are important
>   enough to justify special treatment, and you can see from Figure 1.3 [described above]
>   that a special path is provided through the ALU to make the branch address available half a clock cycle early. **Together with the odd half-clock-cycle shift of the instruction fetch stage**, that means that the branch target can be fetched in time to become the next but one, so the hardware
>   runs the branch instruction, then the branch delay slot instruction, and
>   then the branch target — with no other delays.
>
> ... [don't waste your branch-delay slots]
>
> ... [many MIPS assemblers will reorder instructions for you if it's safe, to hide branch delay]

*See MIPS Run* has a foreword by John L. Hennessy, 
Founder of MIPS Technologies etc. etc..  That's not proof he signed off on everything in the book being accurate, but it's good evidence that the book's description of how MIPS managed this trick is accurate.

It's easily understandable and 100% plausible; we already know the data cache has single-cycle fetch latency (after address-generation in the EX stage).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Thanks.  I happened to be looking for something else (whether `bgezal` was part of classic MIPS I (it is)), and stumbled over the first quote.  IDK what the PDF (which looks OCRed but very nicely formatted) is doing online; this book from 1997/8 is still in copyright and I'm not sure it's supposed to be available for free.  But google found it. >.<

Answer (score 1):

You are actually asking two questions:

1. Is that safe on MIPS I?
2. If so, how?

> Is that safe on MIPS I?

I have seen different block diagrams of MIPS CPUs. Most of them perform the branch decision in the `EX` or even in the `MEM` stage instead of the `ID` stage.

Of course such designs will react differently when your example code is executed.

Without an official statement from the CPU manual of the CPU you are really using, your question cannot be answered with certainty.

(Paul Clayton's answer on [Is that true if we can always fill the delay slot there is no need for branch prediction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114739/is-that-true-if-we-can-always-fill-the-delay-slot-there-is-no-need-for-branch-pr) agrees that one delay slot does fully hide branch latency on MIPS R2000, but not MIPS R4000.  So that's good evidence that real commercial MIPS CPUs work the way the question assumes, despite the existence of various implementations that might not exactly follow the MIPS ISA.)

> If so, how?
>
> Doesn't this mean that branches need their input ready **a cycle earlier** than ALU instructions?

No.

The key is the bypass forwarding logic. Let's take a look at the following example:

```
add  $A, $B, $C      ; Currently in MEM stage
or   $D, $E, $F      ; Currently in EX stage
bltz $G, someLabel   ; Currently in ID stage
```

(While `A`, `B`, ... `G` are GPR numbers.)

The bypass forwarding logic for the EX phase (`or` instruction) contains a multiplexer that works the following way (pseudo code):

```
if E = A
    take ALU input from EX/MEM shift register output
else
    take ALU input from ID/EX shift register output
end-if
```

It is this multiplexer which allows you to use the result of some instruction (`add`) in the following one (`or`).

Of course the same can be done for the `ID` phase using a 3-way multiplexer:

```
if G = D
    take branch decision input from ALU output
else if G = A
    take branch decision input from EX/MEM shift register output
else
    take branch decision input from register bank output
end-if
```

Doing this, the signal propagation time will increase by the time needed in the `EX` phase. This means that this will limit the clock frequency of the processor.

However, the result of some instruction can already be used in the `ID` stage of the next instruction without needing an additional clock cycle.

Comment: @PeterCordes Please see my "Edit 2" section.

Comment: I believe my claims about hiding the branch latency with one delay slot are true of real MIPS I (R2000).  That's the CPU I'm asking about, so yes it makes sense to look at gcc output for it. *I doubt that this information is available publicly* -  I wouldn't be so sure.  Some CPU manuals do get into *very* specific details when they're performance relevant.  And it would have been fairly easy to measure at the time on a real CPU, by testing IPC on code with branches but no other expected stalls and no cache misses.

Comment: I found an authoritative explanation of how it works in an old MIPS book.  Thanks for your contribution, but your answer never explained how EX could get the new PC ready for IF soon enough for 1 branch-delay slot to be enough.