# RISCV: how the branch intstructions are calculated?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, riscv, alu, riscv32

I am trying to understand how modern CPU works. I am focused on RISC-V. there are a few types of branches:

- `BEQ`
- `BNE`
- `BLT`
- `BGE`
- `BLTU`
- `BGEU`

I use a [venus](https://www.kvakil.me/venus/) simulator to test this and also I am trying to simulate it as well and so far so good it works, but I cannot understand, how are branches calculated.
From what I have read, the ALU unit has just one signal output - `ZERO` (apart from its math output) which is active whenever the output is zero. But just how can I determine if the branch should be taken or not based just on the `ZERO` output? And how are they calculated?

Example code:

```
addi t0, zero, 9
addi t1, zero, 10
blt t0, t1, end
end:
```

Example of branches:

`BEQ` - subtract 2 numbers, if `ZERO` is active, branch

`BNE` - subtract 2 numbers, if `ZERO` is not active, branch

`BLT` - and here I am a little bit confused; should I subtract and then look at the sign bit, or what?

`BGE` / `BGEU` - and how to differentiate these? What math instructions should I use?

Comment: a simple comparator just needs to do a lexicographic comparison by comparing from the high bits until it finds a different bit. No need for a subtractor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the ZERO output gives you equal / not-equal.  You can also use XOR instead of SUB for equality comparisons if that runs faster (ready earlier in a partial clock cycle) and/or uses less power (fewer transistors switching).

Fun fact: MIPS only has eq / ne and signed-compare-against-zero branch conditions, all of which can be tested fast without carry propagation or any other cascading bits.  That mattered because it checked branch conditions [in the first half cycle of exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586551/how-does-mips-i-handle-branching-on-the-previous-alu-instruction-without-stallin), in time to forward to fetch, keeping branch latency down to 1 cycle which the branch-delay slot hid on classic MIPS pipelines.  For other conditions, like `blt` between two registers, you need `slt` and branch on that.  RISC-V has true hardware instructions for `blt` between two registers, vs. MIPS's `bltz` against zero only.

---

**Why use an ALU with only a zero output?  That makes it unusable for comparisons other than exact equality.**

You need other outputs to determine GT / GE / LE / LT (and their unsigned equivalents) from a subtract result.

**For unsigned conditions, all you need is zero and a carry/borrow (unsigned overflow) flag**.

---

The sign bit of the result on its own is not sufficient for signed conditions because signed overflow is possible: `(-1) - (-2)` = `+1` : `-1 > -2` (signbit clear) but (8-bit wraparound) `0x80 - 0x7F = +1` (signbit also clear) but `-128 < 127`.  The sign bit of a number on its own is only useful if comparing *against zero*.

If you widen the result (by sign-extending the inputs and doing one more bit of add/sub) that makes signed overflow impossible so that 33rd bit is a signed-less-than result directly.

**You can also get a signed-less-than result from `signed_overflow XOR signbit`** instead of actually widening + adding.  You might also want an ALU output for signed overflow, if RISC-V has any architectural way for software to check for signed-integer overflow.

Signed-overflow can be computed by looking at the carry in and carry out from the MSB (the sign bit).  If those differ, you have overflow.  i.e. SF = XOR of those two carries.  See also http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt for a detailed look at unsigned carry vs. signed overflow with 2-bit and 4-bit examples.

---

In CPUs with a FLAGS register (e.g. x86 and ARM), those ALU outputs actually go into a special register with named bits.  You can look at an [x86 manual for conditional-jump instructions](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc) to see how condition names like `l` (signed less-than) or `b` (unsigned below) map to those flags:

signed conditions:

- `jl` (aka RISC-V `blt`) : Jump if less (`SF≠ OF`).  That's output signbit not-equal to Overflow Flag, from a subtract / cmp
- `jle` : Jump if less or equal (`ZF=1 or SF≠ OF`).
- `jge` (aka RISC-V `bge`) : Jump if greater or equal (`SF=OF`).
- `jg` (aka RISC-V `bgt`) : Jump short if greater (`ZF=0 and SF=OF`).

If you decide to have your ALU just produce a "signed-less-than" output instead of separate SF and OF outputs, that's fine.  `SF==OF` is just `!(SF != OF)`.

(x86 also has some mnemonic synonyms for the same opcode, like `jl` = `jnge`.  There are "only" 16 FLAGS predicates, including `OF=0` alone (test for overflow, not a compare result), and the parity flag.  You only care about the actual signed/unsigned compare conditions.)

If you think through some example cases, like testing that `INT_MAX > INT_MIN` you'll see why these conditions make sense, like that example I showed above for 8-bit numbers.

unsigned:

- `jb` (aka RISC-V `bltu`) : Jump if below (`CF=1`). That's just testing the carry flag.
- `jae` (aka RISC-V `bgeu`) : Jump short if above or equal (`CF=0`).
- `ja` (aka RISC-V `bgtu`) : Jump short if above (`CF=0 and ZF=0`).

(Note that x86 subtract sets CF = borrow output, so `1 - 2` sets CF=1.  Some other ISAs (e.g. ARM) invert the carry flag for subtract.  When implementing RISC-V this will all be internal to the CPU, not architecturally visible to software.)

I don't know if RISC-V actually has all of these different branch conditions, but x86 does.

There might be simpler ways to implement a signed or unsigned comparator than doing subtraction at all.

But if you already have an add/subtract ALU and want to piggyback on that then you might just want it to generate Carry and Signed-less-than outputs as well as Zero.

That way you don't need a separate sign-flag output, or to grab the MSB of the integer result.  It's just one extra XOR gate inside the ALU to combine those two things.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do subtraction to compare two (signed or unsigned) numbers.
You can use cascaded [7485 chip](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc85.pdf) for example.
With this chip you can do all Branch computation without doing any subtraction.

Comment: Yah, i have used this in my prew homeBrew-cpu but then, how useful is that ZERO output from the ALU?