# MIPS program that implements the same algorithm in C

Tags: c, string, assembly, mips

Write a complete MIPS program that implements the same algorithm shown below (in C). To verify the output of the MIPS program, copy this C code and execute it.

So I need to convert this C code to MIP code

This is the C code,

```
int main()
{
  char string[256];
  int i=0;
  char *result = NULL;  // NULL pointer is binary zero

  // Obtain string from user, e.g. "Constantinople"
  scanf("%255s", string); 

  // Search string for letter 'e'.
  // Result is pointer to first e (if it exists)
  // or NULL pointer if it does not exist
  while(string[i] != '\0') {
    if(string[i] == 'e') {
      result = &string[i]; 
      break; // exit from while loop early
    }
    i++;
  }

  if(result != NULL) {
    printf("First match at address %d\n", result);
    printf("The matching character is %c\n", *result);
  }
  else
    printf("No match found\n");
}
```

And this is my Mips code, I am not sure how to get the input, compare and print the result

```
.globl main 
.text   
main:
    #$s0 : base address string
    #$s1 : i
    #$s2 : *result

    la $s0, string
    addi $s1, $zero, 0 
    addi $s2, $zero, 0 #*result = null  


    #get input from user
    li $v0 ,8 # take input
    la $a0, string # load byte space into address
    li $a1, 256 #allot the byte space for string
    move $t0, $a0
    syscall
    addi $t9, $s0, $s1 # &string[i]
    lb $t8,0($t9) #t8 = string [i]
while: beq $t8 , 0, outsidewhile # if string[i] == '\0'
    beq $t8, 101, body # if string i == 'e'
    add $s1, $s1,1 #i++
    j while
body: 
    add $t2, $t9, $zero #result = &string[i];   
    j outsidewhile

outsidewhile :
    beq $s2, 0, printaddress # if(result != NULL)
    # printf("No match found\n");
        li $v0,4
        la $a0, msg2        
        li $v0,4
        la $a0, newline 
printaddress:
    #printf("First match at address %d\n", result);
    #printf("The matching character is %c\n", *result);
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, msg     

li $v0, 10 
syscall

.data
string: .space 256
msg: .asciiz "First match at address "
msg1: .asciiz "The matching character is "
msg2: .asciiz "No match found"
endstring: .asciiz "\0"
newline: .asciiz "\n"
```

Comment: Post the code, not an image.   Are there not enough FAQs?

Comment: I think you are asking about MIPS asm .. not about C.. isn't it?? change tag.. so, others can know it..

Comment: for C, You can use input function in C standard libray... for ASM, you should link others input library and call it..

Comment: alright my bad, here is a C code https://notepad.pw/02sb5cg3

Comment: @PeterLee: Most SO questions about MIPS are using MARS or SPIM which simulate a system with toy system calls that can do integer and string input and output with the `syscall` instruction; no library needed.  The OP's MIPS code is already using `syscall`.

Answer (score 0):

(thanks for posting it). You appear to be using this definition of system calls (https://www.assemblylanguagetuts.com/mips-syscall-services-table/)

Just after the beq instruction in the while: loop, you increment $s1.   I recall that MIPS cpus had a timing bug where it always executed the instruction following a branch.  Here, that would mean that $s1 would be one more than you thought it would.   The same applies to *j while*, but that is innocuous since it will be re-executed on loop exit.

The *j outsidewhile* seems a bit more sinister to me, because the opcode in the delay slot is a branch itself.   Not sure how this resolves, but I wouldn't tempt the gods here.

You need to add the code to print the strings, address and character, and probably an exit.
Beyond that, it looks ok; but you will have some debugging to do.

Comment: Not a timing bug but a design artifact called a branch [delay slot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot).

Comment: To someone like the OP who appears to be fairly new to low-level programming, it may well not be recognizable as humor ...

Comment: He should also know that these design flaws should continue to be considered anachronisms.

Comment: Jokes have to be funny.  Branch-delay slots have a real purpose: fully hide branch latency without needing branch prediction.  [Why does MIPS use one delay slot instead of two?](//stackoverflow.com/q/58422262).  Anyway, most MIPS code on SO is written for MARS/SPIM with their default setting of simulating a MIPS without a branch-delay slot.  (If you don't look at disassembly / machine code, you can pretend it's like an old-school MIPS assembler that reorders your code to fill delay slots, or fills with `nop` if it can't find anything.)

Comment: Of course exposing this classic-MIPS pipeline / microarchitecture detail in the ISA was a burden for later superscalar MIPS implementations that had to preserve the behaviour.  That still doesn't make it a "timing bug", it makes it arguably a premature optimization of the ISA for the first-gen microarchitecture.  Also why MIPS only has simple branch conditions: single reg `bltz` for example (just the sign bit), or for 2 regs only `beq` and `bne`, not `bgt` or `blt` between 2 regs, [so it only takes 1/2 a cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586551)

Answer (score 0):

On line 19 of your provided code, you are using `addi` with 3 register operands.  `addi` requires two register operands and an immediate, so this won't compile/assemble with MARS (I didn't try SPIM).

Your loop fails to (re)load the next byte, so move `while:` back two instructions:  Since you're incrementing `$s1`, you need to reperform the both `add $t9 $s0 $s1` and the `lb $t8 ($t9)` — otherwise, `$t9` doesn't change addresses and `$t8` doesn't change byte values either.