Clarification Needed on Data Hazard in MIPS Assembly Code
I'm working through a problem involving data hazards in MIPS assembly code and need some clarification. Here is the code I'm analyzing:
addi $t0, $s0, 1
lw   $t0, -8($s0)
sw   $t1, -4($t0)
or   $t0, $s0, $t0

The problem asks to identify the hazards, the registers involved, and the best way to resolve these hazards.
One explanation I found states that there is a data hazard between lw and sw due to the dependency on register $t0, which can be resolved using both stalling and forwarding.
However, I'm confused about the potential hazard between addi and lw. The addi instruction updates $t0 by adding $s0 and 1, and the subsequent lw instruction uses $t0 as a pointer. Wouldn't this create a data hazard because lw relies on the updated value of $t0?
To summarize my concern:

addi $t0, $s0, 1 modifies $t0.
lw $t0, -8($s0) then uses $t0.

Doesn't this sequence create a data hazard since lw is using $t0 immediately after it is modified by addi? If so, what is the best way to resolve this hazard?
I analyzed the instruction sequence and identified that addi modifies $t0, and lw then uses $t0. I expected that this would create a data hazard since the lw instruction might try to use the old value of $t0 before addi completes.
However, the provided explanation only mentions a hazard between lw and sw, and does not address my concern about the addi and lw sequence. I need clarification on whether my understanding is correct and, if so, how to best resolve this hazard.

"subsequent lw instruction uses $t0 as a pointer" no it does not. It is using it as destination operand. The pointer is the -8($s0). Writing to $t0 is not a hazard. Of course this means the given example makes little sense.

Am I correct in the understanding that destination or target operands cannot function as a pointer then?
What is it in addi giving $t0 the value it gets that doesn't make it a data hazard? That's where I'm lost.

lw does not depend on the value of $t0 as it is only writing not reading it. Does not matter what its value is, it will be overwritten. No need to wait for the result of the addi.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Does lw not depend on $t0 in the sense that we don't care where in the stack we want to load the value to $t0? Because addi just tells us where in the stack the pointer $t0 is going to point at, and then lw will use the address of the pointer to retrieve the value at base address $s0 with an offset of -8, and load it into $t0. But I'm having difficulty visualizing what's happening in the first two lines, and why there's no data hazard.

Does addi and lw achieve the same thing, manipulating only pointer address?

What in addi $t0, $s0, 1, makes you think that $t0 is a pointer (it could be a pointer but it doesn't have to be), and what makes you think $t0 is related to the stack ($t0 isn't even necessarily a pointer there).

lw is load word. It will read memory at address $s0-8 and put the value into $t0. It only depends on $s0 not $t0. Also none of the instructions deal with the stack.

@ErikEidt  I’m looking for clarity, not argumentation or a debate. If I make a mistake, could you please explain why it’s incorrect instead of posing rhetorical questions? For example, if I incorrectly say "$t0 is related to the stack," it’s due to a lack of knowledge or understanding. Your straightforward guidance would be greatly appreciated.

That's ok.  You seem to need to unlearn something about registers and pointers.  I'm trying to figure out what that is.  So, what in addi $t0, $s0, 1 makes you think of pointers?

You can think of it as $t0 = mem[$s0 - 8] Clearly it does not matter what value $t0 has. Also, as I already said, the first two instructions don't make sense for exactly this reason. It's pointless to calculate $t0 if the value is not used. It's a contrived example.

@ErikEidt In my textbook, for example, it says
addi $sp, $sp, -4 #make space on stack to store one register, which is to make space on a stack. In lectures, they use addi to initialize registers, or increment the address in a register by 4 bytes. So addi can be used for pointer arithmetic to traverse through an array or stack. Hence why I thought intuitively that addi was used to assign some memory address to $t0, the first example was just to demonstrate that there are other uses that I found through reading.

addi has many uses. Use of that instruction does not necessarily imply pointers.

@Jester if the lw instruction achieves $t0 = mem[$s0 - 8], what does addi achieve by contrast? I was taught to separate between word (the actual data), and addresses where the word resides.
And a general question, is overwritten registers fine (i.e. no data hazard occurs?)

In your example, the addi achieves nothing toward advancing the program state.  It is basically a nop since the result is immediately discarded.  However, the processor should do $t0 = $s0 + 1, then discard that. There's no memory involvement there, just a simple addition.  True that we expect $s0 to be a pointer, since it is used in an addressing mode later -8($s0), but that has no bearing on the addi.

So to summarize:

We don't care from where we assign a value to $t0, 2. overwriting it doesn't cause a hazard (and also in general?). (1&2): For example, $t0 could be initialized to 0, and loading some word from a memloc to it shouldn't cause a data hazard.


Unfortunately the lectures didn't do a good job explaining in detail what happens during the 'FDEMW' stages for each instruction, giving rise to a data hazard.

Overwriting, writing, repurposing a register does not cause a hazard in MIPS processors.  More complex processors have more complex problems, so there is a notion of hazard with writing registers, but it isn't a problem on traditional 5-stage MIPS pipelines.

When the sw runs, it reads $t0 in D from the register file, before the value is taken from memory, which happens in M for the preceding instruction.  However, due to the pipelining, the D for the sw happens before the M for the lw.  So, that's a hazard that requires a stall and a forward to mitigate.

Why both forward and stall?  Because the lw produces its value in M, whereas most other instructions produce the desired value in E.  For those other instructions, a forward from E to E is sufficient, but lw is effectively a cycle slower than those others, so we need to wait a cycle, then forward from M to E.

@ErikEidt Thanks for the elucidation. The definition from the course is a DH (atleast RAW) occurs when an instruction reads a register that hasn't been written yet. But it's unclear when we've a register that's definitely been written, if we need to pass a W stage from a preceding instruction, or something else. Say that we've add $t0, $t1, $t2 and sub $t3, $t0, $t4, then they say that the add instruction writes back the value $t0 in cycle 5 (end of M?), but is used in D stage in cycle 3 for the sub instruction. Does lw and sw not work in a similar way here?

I think your last comment gave some necessary context which made my last comment unnecessary longer, namely that lw (and possibly sw) is slower than other type of instructions, and needs to go through the M stage, whereasadd and other instructions have their values available already during the E phase.

sw has its effect in M stage, but since it writes to memory not register there's no pipeline hazard that has to wait for its M to complete.  sw can be the Read in RAfterW but it is not a Write, so unlike lw cannot be the W in RAW.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72017686/471129 for explanation of how W and D can overlap and get the proper answer; this means an instruction just has to reach W but not complete the entire W cycle in order for an overlapping/simultaneous D to get the up-to-date value.
