# how mips stall happen

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

Here is the homework question:
We assume that the MIPS code is executed on a pipelined processor with a 5- stage pipeline, full forwarding, and a branch predictor (The “beq” in label1 predicts branch non-taken for the first time, and then it predicts taken for the following execution. The second “beq” in this code always predicts branch taken, assuming that all the branch prediction are right).
Draw the pipeline execution diagram for this code, assuming there are no delay slots and that branches execute in the EX stage.

```
        lw r2,0(r1)
label1: beq r2,r0,label2 # not taken once, then taken
        lw r3,0(r2)
        beq r3,r0,label1 # taken
        add r1,r3,r1
label2: sw r1,0(r2)
```

Here is the provided answer:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why lw r3,0(r2) start at cycle 6 instead of cycle 3

Can anyone tell me why lw r3,0(r2) start at cycle 6 instead of cycle 3?
Someone told me IF of lw r3,0(r2) should happen after EX in cycle 5. Why should we do this

Comment: It's a simplified-MIPS without delay slots, so `lw` has a control dependency on `beqz r2, label2`.  But yes, with the initial prediction being not-taken, the `lw r3, (r2)` should be fetched in the cycle after the `beq`, and that's the correct path according to your.  Your diagram matches the case where `beqz r2, label2` was predicted taken on the first iteration, causing a mispredict.  (Nothing inside the loop changes `r2`, so I don't understand how the second execution of `beqz r2, label2` can be taken when the first wasn't.)

Comment: Fun fact: real MIPS R2000 only had 1 cycle of branch latency which its 1 delay slot fully hides.  It doesn't need branch prediction.  It forwarded from the first half-cycle of EX to the second half-cycle of IF.  *[How does MIPS I handle branching on the previous ALU instruction without stalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56586551)* - That's why MIPS conditional branches are only on simple conditions like the sign bit and/or all zero (`bltz` `blez`), or compare for exact equality.  With that design, your `lw` could have done its `IF` stage in cycle 5 of your diagram. So I guess it's not that

Comment: Did this diagram come from a book?  Like I said, unless I'm missing something, I think the diagram is wrong for the branch-prediction state you describe.  (But the loop also doesn't make sense because `r2` never changes, and `r3` will only change if that's an MMIO register or if another thread changes the memory `r2` points to.)

Comment: Something is amiss in this explanation.  The lw should start IF in cycle 3, and given a MEM -> EX bypass should complete without further stalling than already incurred.  So, IF in 3, ID in 4, as EX is busy can't  do EX until 5...

Comment: @ErikEidt Sorry I still dont understand. For lw, do you mean IF in 3, ID in 4,  and then EX stall in 5? But why the given answer EX starts at 8?

Comment: @PeterCordes Our TA said this answer is correct and I felt confused too

Comment: What's the exact wording you're given about the initial state of the branch predictor?  This diagram matches an execution where the first `beq` mispredicts, and where taken correctly-predicted branches have a 1-cycle bubble (e.g. if you just have direction prediction but not next-fetch prediction that can predict the existence of a branch before decoding it.)  But like Erik said, if the first `beq` is supposed to predict correctly (not-taken matching the architectural behaviour), we'd expect the `lw` to be fetched in the cycle after the branch.

Comment: @ErikEidt  Sorry guys I got the wrong answer. and I updated the new one from the book, could you please help me why lw r3,0(r2) starts at cycle 6 instead of cycle 3?

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry guys I got the wrong answer. and I updated the new one from the book, could you please help me why lw r3,0(r2) starts at cycle 6 instead of cycle 3?

Comment: The only difference I can see between your image and your ASCII diagram is that the image has the second execution of `beq r2, r0, Label2` in IF in cycle 8, instead of having a fetch bubble after the previous branch was taken.  Everything Erik and I said still applies; if the first branch executed is correctly predicted not-taken, it should start IF in cycle 3.  Unless the diagram is actually wrong, I think the most likely explanation is that you've misread the branch-prediction details.  This diagram would be compatible with an always-taken predictor.  (With no bubble for taken branches)

Comment: Also, you still haven't said what book that's from.