# problem occurred while designing an enhancement pipeline datapath for branches (MIPS)

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, branch-prediction, cpu-hazard

i'm studying MIPS pipeline in Patterson and Hennesy TextBook
this picture below shows the edits for beq instruction :

[image]

The idea is to calculate branch target and detect if taken or not in decode stage, but due to this enhancement, a new data hazard occurred
because forwarding unit solve the data hazard problem by forward the data from Mem stage or writeBack stage to alu stage
but here now te branch takes his operand from decode stage
example :

```
lw $1, 2($10)
add $2, $15, $16
beq $1, $2, addr
```

here the forwarding unit and hazard unit does not support this idea
we either need to stall one cycle (stall in decode or before, not like previous stalls supported in design) or we can find a way to forward the data to decode stage (i think its very hard because the data is not ready yet (still calculating it in alu stage))

i can't fix this issue, is there any possible edits in forwarding unit or hazard detection unit?
or how to stall before decoding stage?

Comment: Real MIPS R2000 kept branch latency down to 1 with a different optimization: running conditional branches in the first half of EX, forwarding to the second half of IF.  (Apparently the clock was so slow that it only needed half a cycle to fetch from I-cache.)  [How does MIPS I handle branching on the previous ALU instruction without stalling?](//stackoverflow.com/a/58601958) - so forwarding inputs to a branch was the same as forwarding to an ALU instruction. Branches having to run in half a cycle is one reason why MIPS doesn't have `bltz` between two regs vs only checking sign bit and zero

Comment: But yeah, with this proposed design, it would have to stall for a cycle unless you can play half-cycle tricks with a load.  But presumably that won't help for forwarding from the add.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks a lot!
but here in this proposed design, how can i support the stall, what is the signals and wires needed because i can't get it

Comment: IDK, sorry.  I just know it's a worse design than what MIPS R2000 actually did. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes Thx anyway :)

Comment: The original MIPS used a branch delay slot tohelp with this.

Comment: @ErikEidt: A delay slot avoids the control hazard of 1 cycle of branch latency.  This question is asking about the data hazard for forwarding inputs to a conditional branch, a different solution to the problem I asked about in [How does MIPS I handle branching on the previous ALU instruction without stalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58601958) (I used to think actual MIPS worked that way, computing branch direction in ID; perhaps I got the idea from this textbook (which I used in undergrad) or from something based on this part of the text, perhaps an old SO comment

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, but doesn't the presence of delay slot allow making the branch decision in EX instead of ID?  If so, that then goes to data hazards..

Comment: @ErikEidt: Allow in what sense?  Doing conditional branches in EX does avoid data hazards, but isn't that orthogonal to whether you hide the 1 cycle of branch latency with a delay slot or not?
  Unless you can make branch decisions in the *first half* of ID (which doesn't seem plausible even w/o forwarding for hazards), you still have 1 cycle of branch latency so you haven't gained anything vs. doing it in the first half of EX, if your IF stage only needs PC to be ready for the second half.  (I guess if IF needs PC at the start of a cycle, branch in EX would have 2 cycle branch latency.)