# How many cycles will it take to execute this assembly code?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu, cpu-architecture

> Suppose that the assembly code is executing on a 32-bit MIPS processor with a 5-stage pipeline that supports stalling but not forwarding. The comparison for branch instructions are done in the execute stage. There are no branch delay slots.  Count the number of clock cycles starting with the fetch cycle of the addi instruction after the foo label, and ending with (including) the fetch cycle of the jr instruction.
>
> ```
> .data
> .align 2
>
> numbers: .space 40
> .align 2
>
> .text
> start:
>     la $a0, numbers
>     addi $a1, $0, 10
>     jal foo
>
> foo:
>     addi $sp, $sp, -4
>     sw $a0, 0($sp)
>
> loop:
>     sw $a1, 0($a0)
>     addi $a0, $a0, 4
>     addi $a1, $a1, -1
>     bne $a1, $0, loop
>
>     lw $t3, 0($sp)
>     addi $sp, $sp, 4
>     lw $t0, 0($t3)
>     lw $t1, 4($t3)
>     add $v0, $t0, $t1
>     jr $ra
> ```

I have calculated the number of missed cycles given the data and control hazards which is 52 cycles in total. I also know that the first instruction `addi $sp, $sp, -4`, will take 5 cycles to finish but afterwards I can just add 1 more for each instruction to come. The total number of instructions executed excluding the first instruction is 47. Then I did: 5 + 47 = 52. So if there were no hazards it would only have taken it 52 cycles but we know there is a delay of cycles so:

Total cycles = 52 + 52 = 104

According to the solution, I am right on the missed cycles part, but instead of 52 they added 48. The "correct" answer is therefore 96 cycles. But that is wrong tho since the program takes longer than 48 cycles to execute even without hazards!

Another question involving this code was whether it will terminate, which it will but they say otherwise in the solution sheet.

Comment: Re: termination: if this program starts executing from `start`, it won't terminate.  `jr $ra` will jump to `foo` (the address after `jal`, before the next instruction), with `$ra` still pointing there.  i.e. it keeps falling back into `foo` after returning to `start`, in an infinite loop.  Until either `addi $a0, $a0, 4` traps on signed overflow (pointer math should be done with `addiu` because the 2GiB boundary isn't special) or `sw $a1, 0($a0)` faults on a bad pointer.  I think the last block is just loading `$t3` from the original `$a0` (could have copied the reg before looping).

Comment: Can you show your work for the breakdown of where those 52 cycles came from?  Perhaps with comments next to the code, or a separate table?  They say branches will execute in EX, but also say no forwarding.  Is branch latency (the number of bubble cycles between exec of a conditional branch to exec of the target) 2 cycles or more?  Or 1 cycle if this is like MIPS R2000 where branches run in the first half of EX and IF only needs an address in the second half?  ([How does MIPS I handle branching on the previous ALU instruction without stalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56586551))

Comment: Note that they say "**ending with (including) the fetch cycle** of the jr instruction."  They don't want you to count cycles until the `jr $ra` reaches WB, just until the next useful work could start executing.  (Except they're omitting the branch latency, so it's not actually the cost in cycles as part of a larger program, which is what we usually want to know.  It would be if it wasn't a branch, though.)  Anyway, this accounts for the 48 vs. 52, I think, you're adding the pipeline length, they only want the IF cycle of the last instruction.

Comment: "*but we know there is a delay of cycles so*" — so how did you compute the stalls?  (It looks like you just doubled the cycle count).

Comment: @ErikEidt because I computed that and got 52 cycles we have to stall.

Comment: Ok, so how can we help if you're sure you've counted correctly and don't want to explain how you computed the stalls?  FWIW, I get 47 for dynamic stall count.

Answer (score 0):

```
.text
start:
    la $a0, numbers
    addi $a1, $0, 10
    jal foo
                        # -- error, missing exit code: after jal foo, 
                        #   foo will run again by accident
foo:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4   # 1 -- error should be addiu for pointer arithmetic
    sw $a0, 0($sp)      # 1+2 stalls on $sp

loop:
    sw $a1, 0($a0)      # 1 (10x)
    addi $a0, $a0, 4    # 1 (10x) -- should be addiu
    addi $a1, $a1, -1   # 1 (10x)
    bne $a1, $0, loop   # 1+2+2 (2 stalls on $a1, and taken branch) 9x
                        # 1+2+2 for last iteration 1x

    lw $t3, 0($sp)      # 1
    addi $sp, $sp, 4    # 1 -- error should be addiu
    lw $t0, 0($t3)      # 1+1 stall on $t3
    lw $t1, 4($t3)      # 1
    add $v0, $t0, $t1   # 1+2 stalls
                        # 1 for $t0 and 2 for $t1
                        # but they overlap, so max(1,2)
    jr $ra              # 1+2 (taken branch)
```

---

| self | RAW stalls | branch stalls | instr. sum | iteration count | total sum | instr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | addi |
| 1 | 2 |  | 3 | 1 | 3 | sw |
| 1 |  |  | 1 | 10 | 10 | sw |
| 1 |  |  | 1 | 10 | 10 | addi |
| 1 |  |  | 1 | 10 | 10 | addi |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 9 | 45 | taken bne |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 5 | not taken bne |
| 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | lw |
| 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | addi |
| 1 | 1 |  | 2 | 1 | 2 | lw |
| 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | lw |
| 1 | 2 |  | 3 | 1 | 3 | addi |
| 1 |  | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 | jr |
|  |  |  |  | 48 | 95 |  |

I'm getting 95; I don't see how to get to 96, but maybe someone can find an error?

Comment: *ending with (including) the fetch cycle of the jr instruction.* - You should be omitting the 2 cycle branch latency from the final `jr`, even though code in the caller can't actually start fetching right away.  Branch latency isn't part of `jr`'s own fetch cycle.  (Also, the OP talked about adding 5 for an instruction to reach the end of WB, which is another discrepancy between their calculation and the assignment question.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, ok, but that takes the count to 93.

Comment: I didn't say it helped explain 96 :P  Hrm, would 96 be the cycle when `jr` reaches WB?  That's not what they asked for, but maybe the OP's inclination to add the pipeline length came from earlier examples that do that, and maybe the "official" answer is doing that even though they actually said not to.